# SQL - query to create custom table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables with data:

**Projects table:**

```
ProjID   Name
 1        A
 2        B
```

**Project Tags table:**

```
ProjID   TagID
 1        1
 2        2
 2        3
```

**Tags Metadata table:**

```
TagID   TagName
 1       Series:Go
 2       Series:Exploring
 3       Chapter:01
```

1. The `ProjID` fild in "Project Tags Table" is foreign key to `ProjID` field in "Projects table".
2. The `TagID` field in "Project Tags Table" is foreign key to `TagID` field in "Tags Metadata table".

Here, projects have tags which are of two types: **Series** and **Chapter**. I need and SQL query to return a custom table associating the Series and Chapter tag names mentioned in the Tags Metadata Table to the respective projects in the Projects Table.

The final table should look like this:

```
ProjID  Name  Series             Chapter
 1       A     Series:GO          null
 2       B     Series:Exploring   Chapter:01
```

Comment: How do you represent the type of tag?

Comment: The tag name starting with "Series:" is a Series tag and the tag name starting with "Chapter:" is aChapter tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select 
 p.projid, 
 p.projname,
 m.tagname, 
 case when substring(m.tagname,1,1) = 'S' then 1 else 2 end tagtype --Type
 from projects p
 left join projecttags t on p.projid = t.projid
 left join tagsmetadata m on t.tagid = m.tagid
) as src

pivot
(max(tagname)
 for tagtype in ([1],[2])
) as pvt;
```

We first create a derived column to check tag type, and then use it along with `PIVOT` to get the desired results.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TMC1196)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your sample data:

```
select p.ProjID, max(p.Name) as ProjName,
max(case when charindex('Series:', t.TagName) > 0 then t.TagName else null end) Series,
max(case when charindex('Chapter:', t.TagName) > 0 then t.TagName else null end) Chapter
from Projects p
join ProjectTags pt on (pt.ProjID = p.ProjID)
join Tags t on (t.TagID = pt.TagID)
group by p.ProjID
```

See the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71f2d/9

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select p.ProjID,Name,case when UCase(SUBSTRING(TagName,1,7))='CHAPTER'
then null else TagName end "Series", 
case when UCase(SUBSTRING(TagName,1,7))='CHAPTER'
then TagName else null end "Chapter"
from TagsMetadata t 
join ProjectTags p on p.TagID=t.TagID
join Projects p1 on p1.ProjID=p.ProjId
```